# How to implement method overload in TypeScript on a plain object?

Tags: typescript

Given this code:

```
type Foo = {
  func(a:string):void;
  func(b:number, a:string):void;
}

const f:Foo = {
  func(b, a) {
    // ???
  }
}
```

I get the error

> Type '(b: number, a: string) => void' is not assignable to type '{ (a: string): void; (b: number, a: string): void; }'.ts(2322)
> index.ts(15, 3): The expected type comes from property 'func' which is declared here on type 'Foo'

I see answers using classes, but how to implement on plain objects?

Comment: For that particular example you can write `func(b, a?) {}` and it'll work, but for more general examples you'd run into trouble.  Does that suffice for you or are you looking for something more general?

Comment: Yeah, it's ugly, but functional. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is apparently unhappy that `func(b, a)` requires a second argument while the `func` method of `Foo` does not.  You can get rid of the error by making `a` [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters) in the implementation:

```
const f: Foo = {
  func(b, a?) {    
  //       ^-- optional
  }
}
```

---

Note that in general it's not always possible to find a way to do this that will compile.  [Overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) *statements* allow their implementation to be more loosely typed than any of the call signatures, but overloaded function *expressions* don't work that way:

```
function barFunc(a: string): number;
function barFunc(b: number, a: string): string;
function barFunc(b: string | number, a?: string) {
  return typeof b === "string" ? b.length : a // okay
}

type Bar = {
  func(a: string): number;
  func(b: number, a: string): string;
}
const g: Bar = {
  func(b, a?) { // error!
    return typeof b === "string" ? b.length : a
  }
}
```

There's a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#47669](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47669) to allow for arrow functions to be overloaded the same way that function statements are, but for now it's not part of the language.

So if you do find yourself with an impossible-to-implement overloaded arrow function, you should either refactor to a function statement:

```
const h: Bar = { func: barFunc }; // okay
```

Or use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to loosen the type checking enough to get it to compile:

```
const i: Bar = {
  func(b, a?) { 
    return (typeof b === "string" ? b.length : a) as any // okay
  }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFKAzArgOwGMAKAQwC4oBnYAJwEt8BzASkoDc56ATAbkxwESAI0r5cAW2ERaAGigVqdRqw5c+6AL7p0hOPho5K8RCgxY8RYsPmkA-CzQCsAehdQ7ngdu070lwmB6fShhUloYITJKGgZmNihxKRl+AKCQsIio0UTJaTkFGOV4orimVKF0-FDwyKsc2JUoAB9c5IL7UpVHcyhaCGBcWmrQSDhsUOQkFAAiRuYZj1CAOgAbCGZgAAsoSlItHVHoACFw5CcLKMV51Tb8-kv6sTyZWy6SpTL+bT0DYCgmJRTrRzr0AtZbA40FA3FAZLQ4LQAITOPoDIYjcAQcaTaazG6LOwrdabHZ7bwHXT6QxbIFnMyCIiUTJ1QhQTS8GHuOAAa1IIB0v0M9DpILMAnBNgUUNQUFR-UGwygxCOOOEU3xxSYhOJGyY212CkcpCoCnwIC5UF5-Ip2iAA)